# MySQL Update Statement isn't working

Tags: java, mysql

**Background:** I am designing a simple GUI application for my school project that has the basic CRUD functions where a user will be able to key in basic transactions into the relevant text fields and the record will be distributed into the database.

**Issue:** Now the Create, Retrieve and Delete functions are working perfectly without any errors. The issue now is that the update function isn't working. I can't determine if it's the error in my method in the JPanel, or is it the method in my Data Access file.

**Note:** All database column tables are correctly spelled, as I am able to create records.

JPanel Method

```
private void updatingTransaction() {
   String tName = UpdateTransaction.txtTName.getText();
   String tID = UpdateTransaction.txtTID.getText();
   String tDetail = UpdateTransaction.txtTDetail.getText();
   String pName = UpdateTransaction.txtPName.getText();
   String pNRIC = UpdateTransaction.txtPNRIC.getText();
   String pDate = UpdateTransaction.txtPDate.getText();
   String pContact = UpdateTransaction.txtPContact.getText();
   String pEmail = UpdateTransaction.txtPEmail.getText();
   String pOrganisation = UpdateTransaction.txtPOrganisation.getText();

   Transaction updateTransaction = new Transaction(tName, tID, tDetail, pName, pNRIC, pDate, pContact, pEmail, pOrganisation);

   if (TransactionDA.updateTransaction(updateTransaction)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TransFrame, "Record successfully updated.");
   } else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TransFrame, "Sorry, there seems to be an error in updating the record.");
   }
}
```

Data Access method

```
public static boolean updateTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    boolean success = false;
    DBControl db = new DBControl();
    String dbQuery; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    db.getConnection();     

    dbQuery = "UPDATE transactioninfo SET tName = ?, tID = ?, tDetail = ?, pName = ?, pNRIC = ?, pDate = ?, pContact = ?, pEmail = ?, pOrganisation = ? WHERE id = ?";
    pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    try {
        pstmt.setString(1, transaction.gettName());
        pstmt.setString(2, transaction.gettID());
        pstmt.setString(3, transaction.gettDetail());
        pstmt.setString(4, transaction.getpName());
        pstmt.setString(5, transaction.getpNRIC());
        pstmt.setString(6, transaction.getpDate());
        pstmt.setString(7, transaction.getpContact());
        pstmt.setString(8, transaction.getpEmail());
        pstmt.setString(9, transaction.getpOrganisation());
        pstmt.setInt(10, transaction.getId());
        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
            success = true;
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(success);
    db.terminate();

    return success;     
}
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Here is the error code returned from the IDE

Comment: Successfully connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost/fypdb.
Database prepared statement: SELECT * FROM transactioninfo WHERE id = ?
Connection has been closed
Successfully connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost/fypdb.
Database prepared statement: UPDATE transactioninfo SET tName = ?, tID = ?, tDetail = ?, pName = ?, pNRIC = ?, pDate = ?, pContact = ?, pEmail = ?, pOrganisation = ? WHERE id = ?
false
Connection has been closed

Comment: Auto commit enabled?  Have you tried committing the transaction?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I have tried commiting it. But it still fails

Comment: @MadProgrammer Auto commit should be the default, I think, with most drivers.

Comment: @GordonSoh Please post the table definition for the `transactionInfo` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It might set by default for most JDBC drivers, but since we don't know if it's been disabled, it's question that needs asking

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hang on gimme a sec

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think so too that autocommit is already enabled by default (well at least on my end)

Comment: @GordonSoh Print the results of `pstmt.executeUpdate()` - it "might" be greater then one - the other thing would be to check that the `id` value is valid

Comment: @MadProgrammer certainly, the result is 1

Comment: I don't see where you set `transaction.id` anywhere.  How does the transaction know which record to update?  You set `tID` but not `id`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your time and efforts to help a lad out. I figured it on my own :D

Comment: @GordonSoh for the effort and time put by the experts here, it would be good to also let us know what the issue was or how it was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @zapping done, the solution I worked out is in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright these are the changes I made to the updatingTransaction.

```
private void updateTheTransaction(int id) {

   String tName = UpdateTransaction.txtTName.getText();
   String tID = UpdateTransaction.txtTID.getText();
   String tDetail = UpdateTransaction.txtTDetail.getText();
   String pName = UpdateTransaction.txtPName.getText();
   String pNRIC = UpdateTransaction.txtPNRIC.getText();
   String pDate = UpdateTransaction.txtPDate.getText();
   String pContact = UpdateTransaction.txtPContact.getText();
   String pEmail = UpdateTransaction.txtPEmail.getText();
   String pOrganisation = UpdateTransaction.txtPOrganisation.getText();

   Transaction updateTransaction = new Transaction(id+1, tName, tID, tDetail, pName, pNRIC, pDate, pContact, pEmail, pOrganisation);

   if (TransactionDA.updateTransaction(updateTransaction)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TransFrame, "Record successfully updated.");
   } else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TransFrame, "Sorry, there seems to be an error in updating the record.");
   }
}
```

and also, because I am calling the method with the use of a JButton, I added these lines of code to the button method

```
btnDone.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int selectedIndex = 0;
            updateTransaction(selectedIndex);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try commiting the connectiong by adding

```
YourConnection.commit();
```

After *pstmt.executeUpdate();*

Comment: The OP already mentioned in the comments that this didn't change the result.